# Warning: To load an ES module, set "type": "module" in the package.json or use the `.mjs` extension

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm developing a Discord bot to train myself with `Node.js` and `JavaScript`.
I want to split each command into a file.

**Index.js**

```js
bot.on("message", (message) => {
    let args = message.content.split(" "); //splits the message into array 
    export {message, args} //export the variables that i need in other files
    switch (args[0]) {
        case "?help":
        require("./commands/help/help.js")
        break 
    }
});
```

**help.js**

```js
import message from "../../index.js"

console.log("[Command] ?help " + message.author);
message.channel.send( { embed: HelpEmbed });
```

The problem is that I get this error:

```
(node:4496) Warning: To load an ES module, set "type": "module" in the package.json or use the `.mjs` extension.
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
```

or when I do not import a message another error says:

```
cannot read the propriety of undefined" or "message is undefined
```

Comment: The error you showed is related to the `import '...' from '...'` that you're using. This is currently restricted unless you set `"type": "module"` in package.json. Or, you could just use `const ... = require('...')`. But your code still isn't going to work, because you didn't export `message` in your main file correctly. I recommend following the [official command handling guide](https://discordjs.guide/command-handling/), which also goes over splitting commands into different files.